# Comparing values in different datasets with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have 4 different csv files in this format: [image: first file] [image: second file]

If there is a date in the other three files that match with a date in the first file I want to append that entire row next to the row in the first file with the matched date. [image: result should be like this]

Any idea how to do it? I have tried iterating through all of them but it takes too long.

```html
<TICKER>;<PER>;<DTYYYYMMDD>;<TIME>;<OPEN>;<HIGH>;<LOW>;<CLOSE>;<VOL>;<OPENINT>
XU100;D;3.07.1987;00:00:00;0,00;0,09;0,09;0,09;0,00;0,00
XU100;D;6.07.1987;00:00:00;0,00;0,091;0,091;0,091;0,00;0,00
XU100;D;7.07.1987;00:00:00;0,00;0,0915;0,0915;0,0915;0,00;0,00
XU100;D;8.07.1987;00:00:00;0,00;0,092;0,092;0,092;0,00;0,00
XU100;D;9.07.1987;00:00:00;0,00;0,093;0,093;0,093;0,00;0,00
XU100;D;10.07.1987;00:00:00;0,00;0,091;0,091;0,091;0,00;0,00
XU100;D;13.07.1987;00:00:00;0,00;0,088;0,088;0,088;0,00;0,00
XU100;D;14.07.1987;00:00:00;0,00;0,0865;0,0865;0,0865;0,00;0,00
XU100;D;15.07.1987;00:00:00;0,00;0,084;0,084;0,084;0,00;0,00
XU100;D;16.07.1987;00:00:00;0,00;0,082;0,082;0,082;0,00;0,00
XU100;D;17.07.1987;00:00:00;0,00;0,086;0,086;0,086;0,00;0,00
XU100;D;20.07.1987;00:00:00;0,00;0,0885;0,0885;0,0885;0,00;0,00
XU100;D;21.07.1987;00:00:00;0,00;0,088;0,088;0,088;0,00;0,00
XU100;D;22.07.1987;00:00:00;0,00;0,09;0,09;0,09;0,00;0,00
XU100;D;23.07.1987;00:00:00;0,00;0,0907;0,0907;0,0907;0,00;0,00
XU100;D;24.07.1987;00:00:00;0,00;0,0918;0,0918;0,0918;0,00;0,00
XU100;D;27.07.1987;00:00:00;0,00;0,0935;0,0935;0,0935;0,00;0,00
XU100;D;28.07.1987;00:00:00;0,00;0,0956;0,0956;0,0956;0,00;0,00
XU100;D;29.07.1987;00:00:00;0,00;0,099;0,099;0,099;0,00;0,00
XU100;D;30.07.1987;00:00:00;0,00;0,1012;0,1012;0,1012;0,00;0,00
XU100;D;31.07.1987;00:00:00;0,00;0,105;0,105;0,105;0,00;0,00
XU100;D;3.08.1987;00:00:00;0,00;0,1065;0,1065;0,1065;0,00;0,00
XU100;D;4.08.1987;00:00:00;0,00;0,11;0,11;0,11;0,00;0,00
XU100;D;5.08.1987;00:00:00;0,00;0,109;0,109;0,109;0,00;0,00
XU100;D;6.08.1987;00:00:00;0,00;0,111;0,111;0,111;0,00;0,00
XU100;D;7.08.1987;00:00:00;0,00;0,1165;0,1165;0,1165;0,00;0,00
XU100;D;10.08.1987;00:00:00;0,00;0,1195;0,1195;0,1195;0,00;0,00
XU100;D;11.08.1987;00:00:00;0,00;0,1215;0,1215;0,1215;0,00;0,00
XU100;D;12.08.1987;00:00:00;0,00;0,1246;0,1246;0,1246;0,00;0,00
```

```html
<TICKER>;<PER>;<DTYYYYMMDD>;<TIME>;<OPEN>;<HIGH>;<LOW>;<CLOSE>;<VOL>;<OPENINT>
AKBNK;D;26.07.1990;00:00:00;0,00;0,00149;0,00143;0,00149;658,99597;0,00
AKBNK;D;27.07.1990;00:00:00;0,00;0,00149;0,00143;0,00149;3355,91846;0,00
AKBNK;D;30.07.1990;00:00:00;0,00;0,00149;0,00143;0,00149;3665,99634;0,00
AKBNK;D;31.07.1990;00:00:00;0,00;0,00149;0,00143;0,00149;6048,35986;0,00
AKBNK;D;1.08.1990;00:00:00;0,00;0,00146;0,0014;0,00143;1062,89514;0,00
AKBNK;D;2.08.1990;00:00:00;0,00;0,00143;0,0014;0,00143;3105,62842;0,00
AKBNK;D;3.08.1990;00:00:00;0,00;0,0014;0,00137;0,0014;1032,51709;0,00
AKBNK;D;6.08.1990;00:00:00;0,00;0,0014;0,00137;0,0014;4189,54883;0,00
AKBNK;D;7.08.1990;00:00:00;0,00;0,00137;0,00132;0,00137;905,57434;0,00
AKBNK;D;8.08.1990;00:00:00;0,00;0,00137;0,00123;0,00137;4343,33936;0,00
AKBNK;D;9.08.1990;00:00:00;0,00;0,00134;0,00129;0,00134;643,92206;0,00
AKBNK;D;10.08.1990;00:00:00;0,00;0,0014;0,00134;0,0014;1080,71924;0,00
AKBNK;D;13.08.1990;00:00:00;0,00;0,00143;0,00134;0,00143;1204,20288;0,00
AKBNK;D;14.08.1990;00:00:00;0,00;0,00149;0,00137;0,00149;6183,09717;0,00
AKBNK;D;15.08.1990;00:00:00;0,00;0,00146;0,0014;0,00146;946,19629;0,00
AKBNK;D;16.08.1990;00:00:00;0,00;0,00146;0,0014;0,00146;1355,35657;0,00
AKBNK;D;17.08.1990;00:00:00;0,00;0,00146;0,0014;0,00146;1271,62439;0,00
AKBNK;D;20.08.1990;00:00:00;0,00;0,00143;0,0014;0,00143;2901,2981;0,00
AKBNK;D;21.08.1990;00:00:00;0,00;0,00143;0,00137;0,00143;1138,16663;0,00
AKBNK;D;22.08.1990;00:00:00;0,00;0,0014;0,00137;0,0014;251,4688;0,00
AKBNK;D;23.08.1990;00:00:00;0,00;0,0014;0,00137;0,0014;675,8252;0,00
AKBNK;D;24.08.1990;00:00:00;0,00;0,0014;0,00137;0,0014;1214,5011;0,00
AKBNK;D;27.08.1990;00:00:00;0,00;0,00143;0,00137;0,00143;2361,32153;0,00
AKBNK;D;28.08.1990;00:00:00;0,00;0,00143;0,00137;0,00143;690,31079;0,00
AKBNK;D;29.08.1990;00:00:00;0,00;0,00143;0,00137;0,00143;1691,58508;0,00
AKBNK;D;31.08.1990;00:00:00;0,00;0,00146;0,00137;0,00146;1685,82117;0,00
AKBNK;D;3.09.1990;00:00:00;0,00;0,00143;0,0014;0,00143;411,88879;0,00
AKBNK;D;4.09.1990;00:00:00;0,00;0,00143;0,0014;0,00143;834,49738;0,00
AKBNK;D;5.09.1990;00:00:00;0,00;0,0014;0,00137;0,0014;202,18799;0,00
```

Comment: Please share the data instead of the images. Just paste a dictionary or the dataframe itself.

Comment: Load each into a dataframe. Then do a merge, one at a time. Something like `df1 = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on=['DTYYYYMMDD', 'TIME'])` Where 'DTYYYMMDD' and 'TIME' are the two columns you are comparing for similarity. If you can share actual sample data (in the form of text) as well as how to compare the datasets for similarity, we can probably help more.

Comment: Just added an example @Zero

Answer (score 0):

1. import every csv into a dataframe:

   import pandas as pd

   df1=pd.read_csv('path to csv1')

   - the same until csv4

   df4=pd.read_csv('path to csv4')
2. Join 4 df in only 1 df:

   df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3,df4])
3. Put the same date all together is the same that order by date

   df=df.orderby(by='YOUR DATE FIELD')

And, it is done.

Saying “thanks” is appreciated, but it doesn’t answer the question. Instead, **vote up** the answers that helped you the most! If these answers were helpful to you, please consider saying thank you in a more constructive way – by contributing your own answers to questions your peers have asked here.

Comment: I need to edit the first csv file not create a new one. And if a date exists in the second file but not in the first I don't want to add it to the first file.